# ActiveDirectoryServer and WSUSServer in one Server

Tags: active-directory, wsus

Can ActiveDirectoryServer and WSUSServer in one Server?
Does it work fine?
Windows Server is 2019 Standard

Comment: Let's not close this question. It's legitimate for a beginner, and people should know it's unwise to run other services on a DC. Whoever doesn't can still learn.

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Applications other than AD DS + DNS + file server increases the attack surface. Also, an update management database is managed quite a bit differently from AD DS, in terms of deployment, maintenance, and capacity planning.

You would want a very good reason to override host level isolation here, and you have not provided one.

Compliance checklists say the security reason, if you want to cite something.  STIG, for example: [Windows Server domain controllers must run on a machine dedicated to that function](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_server_2019/2019-12-12/finding/V-93417)

> Executing application servers on the same host machine with a
> directory server may substantially weaken the security of the
> directory server. Web or database server applications usually require
> the addition of many programs and accounts, increasing the attack
> surface of the computer.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
For security reasons, stop using one server.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, yes, you can do that.

But you really should not.

A Domain Controller should do that and only that (and DNS of course).

Additional technical detail: WSUS needs IIS, which means running a web server on the machine; definitely something to avoid on a DC.

BTW, if you only have one DC, please create another one. Running a single DC is the biggest single point of failure you can create on Windows.

---

If you are resource constrained, install Hyper-V on the system and create virtual machines for each service. It's still not failsafe (if the server breaks down you are screwed), but at least it's a lot cleaner. And if something goes wrong you can simply reinstall Windows (or use a different physical server) and restart the VMs. Make sure to take backups.

Comment: Thank you for answering the details. For security reasons, I will stop using one server.